# plt.fill_between creates unwanted lines

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, polygon, fill

When I use `plt.fill_between(doldurX, doldurY, color='red')`, it creates some unwanted lines through the picture. However, If I use only `plt.fill_between(doldurX, doldurY)`  (W/o color part), it does nor create those lines.

[The picture with lines (Unwanted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlGV3.png)

[Without color part (Clear)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWGTv.png)

Comment: Would `plt.fill_between(...,  facecolor='red')` work?